# to generate a table with list using hbm file

Tags: java, hibernate, arraylist

I am new to Hibernate and trying to make an insertion of `ArrayList<String>` in DB using .hbm mapping file.
I want no annotations to use.
I made a search on how to insert `ArrayList<String>` and found working code from [here](http://www.javatpoint.com/mapping-list-in-collection-mapping).

I was expecting  that a new table containing entries of `ArrayList<String>`  will be created on insert of POJO named **ClassTime**

here is ClassTime.hbm.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Jun 20, 2015 2:47:36 PM by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.img.yogesh.Gym.ClassTime" table="CLASS_TIME">
        <id name="idclass_time" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="IDCLASS_TIME" />
            <generator class="increment" />
        </id>
        <property name="class_name" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="CLASS_NAME" />
        </property>
        <property name="repeat_boolean" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="REPEAT_BOOLEAN" />
        </property>
        <property name="repeat_weeks" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="REPEAT_WEEKS" />
        </property>
        <property name="instructor_name" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="INSTRUCTOR_NAME" />
        </property>
        <property name="start_on_date" type="java.util.Date">
            <column name="START_ON_DATE" />
        </property>
        <property name="start_time_date" type="java.util.Date">
            <column name="START_TIME_DATE" />
        </property>
        <property name="end_on_date" type="java.util.Date">
            <column name="END_ON_DATE" />
        </property>
        <property name="end_time_date" type="java.util.Date">
            <column name="END_TIME_DATE" />
        </property>
        <list name="repeat_days_list" table="repeat_days_list" >
            <key >
                <column name="repeat_id" />
            </key>
            <list-index column="day"></list-index>
            <element type="java.lang.String">
                <column name="REPEAT_DAYS_LIST" />
            </element>
        </list>
        <property name="repeat_days_list_string" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="REPEAT_DAYS_LIST_STRING" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

and java code to save data into database

```
session.persist(addClassTime); 
        transaction.commit();
```

and my stack trace while running the code is

```html
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Table 'gym.repeat_days_list' doesn't exist
 at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatchSerially(PreparedStatement.java:2024)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatch(PreparedStatement.java:1449)
 at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:70)
 at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:268)
 ... 40 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'gym.repeat_days_list' doesn't exist
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1052)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3597)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3529)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1990)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2151)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2625)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2119)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2415)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatchSerially(PreparedStatement.java:1976)
 ... 43 more
```

here is the hibernate.cfg.xml :

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
          "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
          "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<!-- Generated by MyEclipse Hibernate Tools.                   -->
<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/gym</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">root</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property> 
    <mapping resource="question.hbm.xml"/>
    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

hoping to get an answer soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell Hibernate to create the table if it does not already exist. So add this line directly underneath `<hibernate-mapping>` in your `ClassTime.hbm.xml`:

```
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
```

Comment: i found that <property name="hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/> should be added in .cfg file instead of .hbm file . is it so?

Comment: friend your suggestion not worked . its still throwing same stack trace

Comment: can you upload the hibernate.cfg.xml as well then ?

Comment: ok how about in your ClassTime.hbm.xml you have table="repeat_days_list" but the stacktrace is complaining that there is no 'gym.repeat_days_list' so there is a discrepancy there?

Comment: @somggers The `gym` schema is not default schema of mysql server .So referencing to table of that schema needs to specify SCHEMA.TABLE_NAME . So there is no discrepency.

Answer (score 2):

We can do this also with adding

```
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
```

in .cfg.xml file.